# Is there a simpler form for $\sqrt{(-1 +\sqrt{1+8x^2} + 4x^2)/8} \cdot (3 + \sqrt{1+8x^2})/4|x|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I'm trying to find a simpler form for $y=\sqrt{(-1 +\sqrt{1+8x^2} + 4x^2)/8} \cdot (3 + \sqrt{1+8x^2})/4|x|$

This is a "V"-shaped curve that:

- goes through $x=0, y=1$
- asymptotically approaches $y=\frac{|x|+\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{1}{8x+\sqrt{8}}$ as $|x|\to \infty$

but beyond that, I'm stuck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be a positive quantity, so we have;
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{8x^{2}+1}}{8x}\right)\sqrt{\frac{4x^{2}-1+\sqrt{8x^{2}+1}}{2}}$$

Another thing to consider is that for $T_{n-1}=n(n-1)/2$ or the $n$-th *triangular number*, we have
$$\sqrt{8T_{n-1}+1}=2n-1$$

Now keeping this in mind, If we let $x^2=T_{n-1}=n(n-1)/2$,

$$\begin{align}
f(x) & = \left(\frac{3+\sqrt{8T_{n-1}+1}}{8\sqrt{T_{n-1}}}\right)\sqrt{\frac{4T_{n-1}-1+\sqrt{8T_{n-1}+1}}{2}} \\
 & = \left(\frac{3+\left(2n-1\right)}{8\sqrt{T_{n-1}}}\right)\sqrt{\frac{4T_{n-1}-1+\left(2n-1\right)}{2}} \\ 
 & = \left(\frac{1+n}{4\sqrt{T_{n-1}}}\right)\sqrt{2T_{n-1}+\left(n-1\right)} \\
 & = \left(\frac{1+n}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{n\left(n-1\right)}}\right)\sqrt{n\left(n-1\right)+\left(n-1\right)} \\ 
 & = \left(\frac{1+n}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{n\left(n-1\right)}}\right)\sqrt{n\left(n-1\right)+\left(n-1\right)} \\ 
 & = \left(\frac{1+n}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{n\left(n-1\right)}}\right)\sqrt{\left(n-1\right)\left(n+1\right)} \\ 
 & = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{3}}{2n}}\tag{1}
\end{align}$$

Now what we have to do is substitute the value of $n$ in $x$. We have defined $n$ as;

$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=x^2$$
$$\Rightarrow n^{2}-n-2x^{2}=0$$

Evaluate this as a quadratic equation and find $n$ using the quadratic formula:

$$n=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{8x^{2}+1}\right)$$

Substitute this in $(1)$ and we finally get;
$$\small{\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{1+8x^{2}}}{8x}\right)\sqrt{\frac{4x^{2}-1+\sqrt{1+8x^{2}}}{2}}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\left(3+\sqrt{8x^{2}+1}\right)^{3}}{1+\sqrt{8x^{2}+1}}}}$$

EDIT: I just realized, in your question there is a near miss, we can denest:
$$\sqrt{4x^{2}\color{red}{+}1+\sqrt{8x^{2}+1}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{8x^{2}+1}}{\sqrt{2}}$$